# SQL query join elements

Tags: sql-server

I will re-write my doubt to be more easy to understand.
I have one table named `SeqNumbers` that have only one column of data named `PossibleNumbers`, that has value from 1 to 10.000.
Then I have another Table named `Terminals` and one of the columns have the serial numbers of the terminals. What I want is get all the `SerialNumbers` that not exists in the `Terminals` table from 1 to 10.000. 
I've created the `SeqNumbers` table only to do this... maybe there's another solution without using it... that's fine to me.
The query I have is:

```
SELECT PossibleNumbers from SeqNumbers 
Where PossibleNumbers NOT IN (SELECT SerialNumbers from Terminals)**
```

Basically I want to list ALL serial numbers of terminals that doesn't exists in the database.
This Query works fine I think... but the problem is that I don't want all results in a single column.. I want these results displayed in 4 or 5 columns. 
For my purpose I can only use the results from the query like that. I cannot use programmatically methods to do that.

Hope this is more clear now... Thanks for all the help...

Comment: Can we see the query?  (Or a sufficiently disguised version of it)

Comment: @Carlos: please tag your questions with whatever language or technology you are using (e.g. SQL, Java, .NET, etc.). You will get many more viewers because of the interesting tags list.

Answer (score 2):

```
select x, x+1000  from tablename
```

Will that do it for you?

Comment: Sorry for downvote, because I know the question changed on you.  But this is not what he wants and we need to get a better answer voted above this one.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this right, you'd probably have to do a self join; something like:

```
SELECT
   LeftValues.ColA,
   RightValues.ColA AS ColB
FROM YourTable LeftValues
    LEFT JOIN YourTable RightValues ON LeftValues.ColA = RightValues.ColA - 1000
WHERE LeftValues.ColA < 1000
```

Note: Use the JOIN that makes sense for you (left if you are willing to accept NULLs in ColB, inner if you only want them where both values exist)

Comment: I don't understand your query... I will describe exactly what I want maybe I have not been clear... sorry.
I have one table TabA that I'd created with a single collumn with numbers from 1 to 10.000. I have another table TabB with some data and one of the collumns are serial numbers os products. I want to know all the serial number that DOESN'T exist in that TabB from 1 to 10.000. I already made that query with IS NOT in... but I get all results in one single collumn. Now I want to separate this results by multiple collumns. Imagine, 100 for each one for example. 5 ou 6 collumns would be nice.

Comment: So it sounds like what you are wanting is entirely for display purposes and that the ColA and ColB values have no correlation? My query is based on the assumption that the values are mathematically correlated (eg, colA = ColB - 1000).  While a non-correlated solution is possible in SQL, it probably will not be the best approach; You probably should return the query to some application as is and let that application display it however you need it to.  If a SQL solution is required, update your question to include more detail/better example and tags to include your SQL dialect.

Comment: Hi Chris, I updated my question .. may be you can understand it better now. I cannot use another application to do the job.. i really have to have multiple collumns with the results.. and as you can see now there is no mathematical correlation between the numbers... Hope you can help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scripting language to parse the MySQL results to format it anyway you like. Are you using PHP to access the database?  If so, let me know and I can cook one up for you.

I just saw your new updated question.  In this case the order of the columns will be ordered by your `SELECT` statement and you can also sort too.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM my_table ORDER BY Column1, Column2 ASC
```

Comment: No I'm not using PHP. I just want to make a query in the SQL Server to get the results... I have explained better what I want in the answer of Chris Shaffer.

Thanks guys for all the help... this is a odd query for me and I really need it.